# Prove That If $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \operatorname{Row} A$ and $\vec{x} \ne \vec{y}$, then $A\vec{x} \ne A\vec{y}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I was watching a [lecture](https://youtu.be/Go2aLo7ZOlU) on YouTube on Pseudo-Inverses, and the professor brought up the claim that is the title of this post. I didn't watch the rest of the lecture in hopes of coming up with a proof of this.

I don't know if it's sound, however. Here goes:

Assume that there exists vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ in the row space of a matrix $A$ such that $A\vec{x} = A\vec{y}.$ Then, $\vec{x} - \vec{y}$ would be in the nullspace of $A$, since $A\vec{x} = A\vec{y} \implies A(\vec{x} - \vec{y}) = \vec{0}.$ Since $\operatorname{Row} A$ is a subspace, then $\vec{x} - \vec{y}$ is also in the row space of $A$. This means that $\vec{x} - \vec{y} \in \operatorname{Row} A \cap \operatorname{Nul} A$. However, $\operatorname{Row} A \cap \operatorname{Nul} A = \{\vec{0}\}$, since those two subspaces are orthogonal complements. (The only vector that lives in a subspace and it's orthogonal complement is the zero vector.) Hence, $\vec{x} - \vec{y} = \vec{0} \implies \vec{x} = \vec{y}.$

We've shown that if $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ are in the rowspace with matching outputs when left multiplied with $A$, then they're equal. Therefore, the proof by contrapositive is completed.

Is this an ok argument?

Comment: "since those two subspaces are orthogonal complements" - This does not hold in all sorts of fields. If you assume that the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, you should mention this somewhere. Other than that, the argument is ok.

Comment: I have philosophical qualms with mixing spaces of row vectors and spaces of column vectors so readily. But it's easy enough to inject transpositions everywhere to make it actually work, so it's not a huge issue.

Comment: @Arthur Wouldn’t row vectors just be vectors that live in the same vector space as the null space vectors? As in, wouldn’t addition, say, be defined for a vector that is in the null space of a matrix and the row space of the matrix without invoking transposes? I’ve always assumed that they were column vectors as well, or that it doesn’t make a difference.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier I see. Is the claim true for any field however? Or are there fields where the claim itself fails?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Also, how does the proof fail for different fields? I’ve always assumed that our sense of orthogonality came from an inner product defined on the space, and one of the main “rules” that the inner product must satisfy is that it is a positive-definite form. (That is, $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{x}\rangle = 0 \implies \vec{x} = \vec{0}$ holds.). I’m definitely interested in learning more about this. Are there fields where the inner product doesn’t have to be positive-definite?

Comment: The existence of matrix multiplication, row spaces, column spaces, null spaces etc. is independent of the field. But the existence of a positive-definite inner product is not. Take, for example $\mathrm{GF}(2)^2.$ You get $\left\langle\binom{1}{1},\binom{1}{1}\right\rangle = 0$. The row space and the null space of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are not orthogonal, they are identical.